# Add all objects with the same id from one array into an array of an object with the same id in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 2 arrays. I need to move all the objects that have the same id in arraySecondary into an array inside an object with the same id in arrayPrimary.

Example:

```
    const arrayPrimary = [
      { "id": "1", "location": "France", "price": "12,3" },
      { "id": "2", "location": "Germany", "price": "12,0" },
      { "id": "3", "location": "USA", "price": "10" },
      { "id": "4", "location": "Italy", "price": "16" },
    ];

    const arraySecondary = [
      { "id": "1", "name": "phil", "location": "New York", "price": "1,3", "dd": "lql" },
      { "id": "2", "location": "Paris", "dd": "lql" },
      { "id": "3", "location": "Egypt" },
      { "id": "2", "name": "joe", "location": "London" },
      { "id": "1", "location": "location", "name": "april" },
      { "id": "2", "name": "mei", "location": "Barcelona" },
    ];
```

Expected result:

```
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        location: "France",
        price: "12,3",
        area: [
          { id: 1, location: "location", name: "april" },
          { id: 1, name: "phil", location: "New York", price: "1,3", dd: "lql" },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        location: "Germany",
        price: "12,0",
        area: [
          { id: 2, location: "Paris", dd: "lql" },
          { id: 2, name: "joe", location: "London" },
          { id: 2, name: "mei", location: "Barcelona" },
        ],
      },
      { id: 3, location: "USA", price: 10, area: [{ id: 3, location: "Egypt" }] },
      { id: 4, location: "Italy", price: 16 },
    ];
    //or json
```

First i add an empty array to each object in arrayPrimary.

```
 arrayPrimary.map((v) => ({ ...v, area: [] }));
```

After that i filter arraySecondary by id and push all the results into area array in each object in arrayPrimary. But here i get stuck.

```
    console.log(
      arrayPrimary.forEach((main) =>
        main.area.push(arraySecondary.filter((items) => items.id === main.id))
      )
    );
```

Second idea is to first order each object in arraySecondary by id and then push that into empty area array in arrayPrimary

```
let op = arrayItems.reduce((op,inp) => {
  op[inp.id] = op[inp.id] || []
  op[inp.id].push(inp)
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

And this is where i am stuck with both ideas.

Comment: Concatenate them and then use one of the "[javascript array of objects group by key](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+array+of+objects+group+by+key+site%3Astackoverflow.com)" questions here on SO to group them by `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```js
const arrayPrimary = [
      { "id": "1", "location": "France", "price": "12,3" },
      { "id": "2", "location": "Germany", "price": "12,0" },
      { "id": "3", "location": "USA", "price": "10" },
      { "id": "4", "location": "Italy", "price": "16" },
    ];

    const arraySecondary = [
      { "id": "1", "name": "phil", "location": "New York", "price": "1,3", "dd": "lql" },
      { "id": "2", "location": "Paris", "dd": "lql" },
      { "id": "3", "location": "Egypt" },
      { "id": "2", "name": "joe", "location": "London" },
      { "id": "1", "location": "location", "name": "april" },
      { "id": "2", "name": "mei", "location": "Barcelona" },
    ];
    
const composed = arrayPrimary.map(d => {
  return {
    ...d,
    area: arraySecondary.filter(({id}) => d.id === id)
  }
})

console.log(composed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as followed :

```
const arrayResut=arrayPrimary.map(primaryElement=>{
   primaryElement.area=arraySecondary.filter(secondaryElement=>secondaryElement.id==primaryElement.id);
   return primaryElement;
})
```

This will create a copy of `arrayPrimary`, and in the process add an `area` key which will contain all the elements of `arraySecondary` if the id of the `arraySecondary` element is equal to the id of the `arrayPrimary` element.